# Why i get (BLOB) value in result instead INT value

Tags: mysql, sql, centos, navicat

When i execute about three queries that is UNION ALL it normal display INT value in column, but when i do UNION ALL on about 15 queries, in one column it display (BLOB) value, MySQL service is running on CentOS, i checked configuration of mysql service, i set everything on higher size, i added **group_concat_max_len** but that haven't helped me

Now, result looks like:

```
id    id_department   id_department_relase   some_column
1        (BLOB)            10                 some data
```

but it should look like this:

```
id    id_department   id_deparment_relase    some_column
1        5                 10                 some data
```

P.s When i copy column where is (BLOB) in Excel i get normal int values

Comment: When faced to mixed types MySQL will cast to a common type that can hold both values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem have been solved, because i use UNION ALL with multiple SELECT queries, i one query, i missed order of columns, and i tried to insert text varchar value in int column, and that is reason why result results as (BLOB)